# Using system command with the new ubuntu in cmd

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmd

I have an issue where I would want the code to execute a Linux command using ubuntu's cmd interface in windows 10. When using

```
system("ubuntu");
```

The code would switch from cmd to Linux. When I would want to use the speedtest program on Linux using the same line

```
system("speedtest");
```

The code would not work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: is that application in path? When you type speedtest at the linux bash prompt, what does it happen?

Comment: Each call to `system` will fork a new process and start a new shell. So there's no way to do this with two calls to `system()`. You *may* be able to get away with something like `system("ubuntu; speedtest")` to send both to the same shell, but I'm not sure how the windows shell interprets that. Does the `ubuntu` command have an option to take a string to pass to the linux shell? That'd make things easy...

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It is a resource pack called speedtest-cli

Comment: @mohsen are you trying to do that from the same app? It won't work. A Windows app does not see an app designed to run inside ubuntu.

Comment: @scohe001 not exactly *fork*, there is no fork in Windows. It will just start a new process.

Comment: Ahh I guess my lack of Windows knowledge is showing @Michael. It'd be forking a new process if this were linux...I'm sure something similar is happening in windows to make these run in two shells that have nothing to do with each other though, no?

Comment: @scohe001 In Windows you have no way to copy the current state of a process to the new process, even if's the same executable. However your original comment was correct; The proper, if any way ,would be to run something like system("ubuntu /run speedtest"), if ubuntu.exe in windows takes a command line parameter like that.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I just had to type in system("ubuntu run speedtest"). Thanks for the help guys!